# layout width changing weirdly in rows of Custom Listview

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have a Custom Listview which is used as a Conversation like layout(ex.Whatsapp)..the layout is creating without any errors but the width of some rows are not correctly wrapping according to the content it has....

this is the layout file of Custom row

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/messagecontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chatbubblellayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/left"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chatbubbletv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="HI.."
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"


                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chatbubbletvdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:gravity="top|end|right"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="05/27/2018"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="8sp" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/chatbubblepb"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                 />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/chatbubbleiv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"

                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxHeight="15dp"
                android:maxWidth="15dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/tick" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]"

The image shows what i'm getting..those black circled ones are showing that weird behavior

any help would be appreciated...

Comment: add your adapter code too. I think additional space added to message. Use trim function to trim leading and trailing spaces

Comment: why `android:layout_width="0dp"` instead of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` ?

Comment: @USKMobility but when scrolling, sometimes those rows are getting as expected in wrapped..if there are any white spaces i guess it cant be happened right..

Comment: As Lino said, that weight seems to have no sense in this case, try to set width to wrap_content

Comment: @Lino that is because i need to give the remaining space to the textview..and also the layout should show date and tick every time without any cropping

Comment: Then I think you should write a more complex layout, in order to prevent a potential cropping

Comment: removing weight and put the width in "wrap_content" seems solved it...it's weird last time I checked it doesn't work now it does...any way thank guyz..